Content overlaps with floating table of contents in R markdown file when scrolling horizontally
I recently learned that it's possible to use toc_float: true in a Rmd file's YAML header to create a sticky table of contents that is placed to the left of the Rmd file's contents. This is great because I am currently dealing with a very long document containing many headers that benefits greatly from this navigation feature.
I noticed, however, that the TOC does not work nicely when main content overflows the default width. A scrollbar appears at the bottom, but when you use it the content will overlap with the table of contents.
In my case I am using a DT::datatable() HTML widget to display a data frame. As the data contains many columns, it is perfectly expected that the table will not fit inside the HTML container. Therefore, my question is not "how do I make my datatable smaller".
Is there a way to keep all the contents of the Rmd file to the right of the TOC even when scrolling horizontally? I don't mind if it's a hacky HTML/CSS solution either.
Below are the code for my example and two screenshots that show the problem. (Note that I wrote "THREE BACKTICKS" as I can't write them out normally due them being recognized as code regions in stackoverflow's text editor.) Thanks a lot in advance!
---
title: "rmd floating toc test"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

## level 2 title

bla bla bla


### level 3 title

bla bla bla

THREE BACKTICKS {r, echo=FALSE}
Sys.setenv(LANG="en")
library(tidyr)
DT::datatable(billboard)
THREE BACKTICKS




You can set the position of the toc to relative instead of fixed so it's not floating, but it will not float either when you scroll down.
Add this just below the YAML header:
```{css toc-content, echo = FALSE}

#TOC {
  position: relative !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

```

